# Encoding PHP to send mails in other languege

Tags: php, encoding

I want to encode my php sending form in my language. 
What is wrong with the code? I have added the content-type in the $headers at the end... It is not the whole file, there is also HTML after the PHP, but did not let me to post it

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "gancho_lambev@abv.bg";
    $email_subject = "Contact Form...";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form your submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form your submitted.');      
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required




    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  ;}
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? To have php automagically translate your e-mails for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a 3rd party library, like phpmailer:

Example: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleamail
Download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/

Don't forget to set the charset, like this:

```
<?php
require_once '../class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

try {
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks you. God bless you. It did not worked this way, i don't know what happened. I am beginner in PHP. Thank you for your help man.

Comment: every one of us was a beginner once, i know it was frustrating :) 
But use the simple example of @Sudhir. in your question, you just have to change the encoding to utf-8

Answer (score 1):

For sending mails in different language, you can just change the charset:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

And be sure the page is encoded as UTF-8 and that if a database is used, the table ( or whole db ) is in "UTF-8 unicode general"

With UTF-8 you can write the characters as they appear, don't use entities.

Do you mean something like this. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks you. God bless you. It did not worked this way, i don't know what happened. Thank you for your help ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Set the collation of your database/ tables/ rows to UTF-8. `UTF8_general_ci` should do.
Set the connection between MySQL and PHP to `UTF-8`. (By executing the query SET NAMES 'utf8' after connecting or by setting the default connection encoding).
Try sending the content-type header with PHP: `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`.

Comment: Thanks you. God bless you. It did not worked this way, i don't know what happened. I am beginner in PHP. Thank you for your help man.